# Angular2 Typescript app throws 404 on components when js extension not specified

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, polyfills

I just started to play around with Angular2, and ran into a weird component file extension problem:

Let's use the [5 minutes quickstart demo from angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) (I'll reproduce the code here for reference).

**File structure**

```
angular2-quickstart
|- app
|  |- app.component.ts
|  |- boot.ts
|
|- index.html
|- package.json
|- tsconfig.json
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^1.3.1",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**app/app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**app/boot.ts**

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

**index.html**

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

This works like a charm, but exposes the whole file structure, including `node_modules` and the configuration, which seems like a bad idea.

So I tried to expose only the `app` folder. To achieve that, I did the following:

- Copy the referenced javascript files in an `app/scripts` folder
- Move the `index.html` in `app`
- Change the references paths in this file
- Change the `lite` script in `package.json` to `lite-server --baseDir app`

When running this, everything worked, except that `angular2-polyfills.js` returned :

```
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app.component(…)
  run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138
  zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111
  lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:1511
  lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:1523
  lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:1494
  lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publishRejection @ angular2-polyfills.js:1444
  (anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:243
  run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111
  lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:1305
```

Of course, if I ask for `http://localhost:3000/app.component.js` the file is returned correctly.

So my question is: why doesn't the `.js` extension get appended to `app.component`, resulting in this error, where that worked when the server baseDir was the root of the project ? Did I miss some configuration option ?

Comment: That's because you removed `app/` from the file location. Check [`packages`](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#packages) documentation. When systemjs sees `app/...` in your paths it will apply the default extension. So you should be good to go by changing your file path to `app/app.component`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can configure the path to your app folder. In my case, I'm using angular 2 to produce a mobile version of our app and had to configure System like so:

```
System.config({
            paths: {
                'app/*': './js/mobile/dist/*'
            },
            packages: {        
              app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
              }
            }
          });
          System.import('app/main')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

As you can see, I decided to map "app" to "dist" where I have my compiled js files to keep them separate from the ts files.

Answer (score 7):

This problem may be caused by JetBrains WebStorm when refactoring files to new locations. It seems to append the .ts extension on imports.

So, keep your new files in their places but check every file's imports.

All of your imports should resemble this

```
import {MyComponent} from './Components/MyComponent';
```

And not this

```
import {MyComponent} from './Components/MyComponent.ts';
```

Answer (score 4):

In my `boot.ts` file I changed this line:

`import {AppComponent} from './app.components'`

and it works. I reported to Google today as well.

Comment: My savior!  Such a dumb easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it is resolved when added `module.id`

```
@Component({
    ***moduleId: module.id,***
    providers : [MyService],
    templateUrl: 'sandbox.component.html',
})
```

Comment: if you are still using angular 2, module.id usage was resolving, but if you use recent angular/cli (angular 4) , it does not require, but template url should have relative urls like ' ./sandbox.component.html' .. install some url identification extensions in vscode, that would help to realize the correct paths.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing app/main.ts. It's only a few lines, so it's fairly easy to miss in the quickstart.

Comment: Seems that this file was called `boot.ts` when I looked at that tuto. That wouldn't have produced the same error though, and I guess I would have figured this one out :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with chrome, after pulling my hair out for a while I tried turning off adblock and it worked after that. If you have adblock, it's probably the culprit

Answer (score 0):

after trying many other solutions suggested by others, I found out it can case by [dots in filenames](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/756) and these two solutions worked for me.
first:

```
defaultJSExtensions: true,
```

but [defaultJSExtensions is a property that will be deprecated in future](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/756#issuecomment-137708647)
and second:

```
packages: {
            '.': {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
```